# Painted double basin metal utility sink. Is this worth cleaning up?

Tags: sink, paint-removal, oil-based-paint

The utility sink in my house is disgusting.  My wife wants me to pitch it and buy a new one.  I hate those cheap plastic sinks and I was curious so I jumped online so see what they were selling for. I found a single basin going for $300.

My question is simple.  is this worth cleaning up and keeping?  The paint is oil based, so it took 10 minutes to remove a few square inches.  It looks pretty nice underneath though.  I'm not certain what type of metal it is.  It doesn't seem to be rusting, so I was guessing bronze since it is quite dark.

Second question.  If it is worth keeping I'm thinking I need to chemically strip this.  I'm going to destroy my drill doing this. Any advice on how?

Answer (score 2):

Paint strippers good for oil paints are readily available.  One popular one is called "Aircraft remover".  It will go after alkyd enamels and lacquer paints quite effectively if used as directed.

Don't assume the paint is "oil based" merely because it is not latex based.  There are some much more durable coatings out there, most of them 2-part like an epoxy.

A great many such sinks are made of galvanized steel wrapping around concrete.  If they are heavily rusted, they may look black.

Comment: A word on the Aircraft stripper (I've used it on particularly stubborn and hard polyester - yes polyester - guitar finish): use gloves and goggles.  Like, chemical gloves.  And probably also an apron and some sort of breathing protection.  Whatever it says on the can.  That stuff is *nasty* (made to strip the paint off of aluminum aircraft).